# "File is encrypted or is not a database" error is coming when trying to decrypt an encrypted database in android

Tags: android, encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

I am encrypting a sqlite database in ubuntu terminal using sqlcipher version 3.7.17 and sqlite3 version 3.7.15.2. When i am trying to use this encrypted database in android, i am getting the error "File is encrypted or not a database". I am using sqlcipher version 2.2.0 in android.

Encryption code used in ubuntu terminal:
./sqlcipher plaintext.db 
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey'; 
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted'); 
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;

Android code to decrypt:
    SQLiteDatabase database= SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, testkey", null);

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I can't help in your problem, it would help people who can help you if you post some code.

Comment: Um, there is SQLCipher 3.7.17 AFAIK. The latest is 3.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQLCipher core 3.7.17, that is the SQLite version string which corresponds to the `v2.2.1` tag of SQLCipher which will work properly with SQLCipher for Android 2.2.0.  To verify your initial encryption is working properly, following the `sqlcipher_export` process, please do the following:

```
$> ./sqlcipher encrypted.db
sqlite> PRAGMA key = 'testkey';
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
```

If you get results displayed from the query of the `sqlite_master` table, we should rule out an application integration issue, could you try running your database within the SQLCipher for Android [test suite](http://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/)?  Please note that the test suite is targeting the latest SQLCipher for Android libraries, currently 3.0.2 and will require using a different key derivation length; 4000 was the default value in SQLCipher 2.x.  You will want to copy your database file into the `assets` directory and then attempt opening it using the following example:

```
SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook(){
  public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase database){}
  public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase database){
    database.execSQL("PRAGMA kdf_iter = 4000;");
};
ZeteticApplication.getInstance().extractAssetToDatabaseDirectory("encrypted.db");
File databaseFile = ZeteticApplication.getInstance().getDatabasePath("encrypted.db");
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, "testkey", 
                                                              null, hook);
```

From there you should be able to query your database.  If you have a particular question, the [SQLCipher Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/) is also a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your response. I tried the Android test suite and also the SQLiteDatabaseHook but still getting the same error. I am trying to decrypt an existing database in android which i have encrypted in Ubuntu terminal using sqlcipher version 3.7.17 and sqlite3 version 3.7.15.2